# SQL Server Agent refuses to start

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, sql-server

I'm having a problem with SQL Server 2005 where the SQL Server Agent suddenly refuses to start. If I attempt to start it through Services, I get the error "SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) service on Local Computer started and then stopped." In the Application log, I have the following entry:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   SQLSERVERAGENT
Event Category: Service Control 
Event ID:            103
Date:       5/20/2010
Time:       11:07:07 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:            SHAREPOINT
Description:
SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: Unable to connect to server 'SHAREPOINT'; SQLServerAgent cannot start).
```

This database has been running fine for four months. It contains a SharePoint configuration database, which two days ago stopped working, throwing me a message that the configuration database cannot be reached. It was then that I realized the SQL Server Agent was not running, and I have been unable to restart it. I have tried running it with both the local system account and the network service account, with the same results. So far, I have tried:

- Granting the administrators group, network service, and SharePoint SQL Server Agent account public and sysadmin roles on the database.
- Granting the administrators group, network service, and SharePoint SQL Server Agent account full permissions to the entire MSSQL directory and all files within.

I still have no joy.

Comment: is the VIA protocol running?

Comment: Have you rebooted the machine yet? What other trouble shooting steps have you taken?

Comment: Is the SQL Server itself running? SQL Server agent needs SQL Server to be running...

Comment: VIA is not installed at all, and I've restarted a few times with no luck. I'm really not even sure where to go from here.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server is running fine, and I am using the same account for it as I am trying to for the SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this site has some troubleshooting steps you can try:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/06/12/unable-to-start-sql-server-agent.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could try running [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals, filtering out that particular process, and seeing where it's failing: i.e. is it having DNS issues?  Missing registry key? You'll see some low-level errors that may help you isolate what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't use ProcMon much, but I just tried it and SQLAGENT90.EXE is throwing tons of NAME NOT FOUND errors and buffor overflows. I don't really know which are important, but one that sticks out is the NAME NOT FOUND error on the "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo" key. I don't have that key in the registry and it seems like I should. Overall, there are about a thousand errors thrown by SQLAGENT90.EXE and the vast majority are NAME NOT FOUND and BUFFER OVERLOW. It's overwhelming. Do you have a suggestion of which ones to start with?